# How can i get the data from string in desired formate to have data of NSData type

Tags: ios, swift

```
func callAddWithPOST(Name mname:String, PhoneNo mphone:String, Email memail:String, Comment mcomments:String)
{
    var names = [String]()
    let login = ["countryId":"1"]
    print("Your Result is : = \(login)")
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://photokeeper.mgtcloud.co.uk/commonwebservice.asmx/getStateList")!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    do
    {
        let auth = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(login, options: .PrettyPrinted)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = auth
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            let responseString = String(data:data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let validresponseString = "\(responseString!)"
            print(validresponseString)
            let badJsonString = "This really isn't valid JSON at all"
            let jsonData = validresponseString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let badJsonData = badJsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            do
            {
                let parsed = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
                let otherParsed = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(badJsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
            }
            catch let error as NSError
            {
                print("Done.")
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

I am in search of one solution for fetching the desired data from this method,i want to display `StateID` and StateName from this string data. i can not convert the string "responseString" in `NSData` to have this string as `NSData` to fetch the desired record. Will any body please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: What is the format of your JSON data ?

Comment: My data is string in form of json.

Comment: *You are downloading JSON data then converting this data to String then again converting this string to data!* This is the first thing you should fix: decode your JSON data as soon as it's donwloaded - do not convert to String. Downcast the result to a dictionary and print/observe the structure, then use subscripting to fetch the values. There's many examples on this site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value for key from a json you should convert the json to Dictionary with this code:

#### Swift 3

```
JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
```

#### Swift 2

```
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
```

let me know in the comments if I misunderstood something before the downvote, thank you.